# Regex to match URL string between 2 other strings *and then* replace some of the text

Tags: regex, replace

I'm trying to extract the LinkedIn profile URL from incoming email notifications.

Here is a sample of text:

```
View profile: https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&trk=4ceml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta&trkEmail=3Deml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta-null-21a89%dopkdokpokks%7Ezx-null-neptune%2Fprofile%7Evanity%2Eview&lipi=6guge%3Ali%3Apage%3Aemail_email_accept_invite_single_01%j3oijsdoij3oi%2FopIi4P20rA%3D%3D
```

I only want to extract the profile URL and none of the queries so the matching string would be:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/profile-name-12345678

I can match the URL using [this Regex](https://regex101.com/r/ffHG3O/1):

```
(?<=View profile: )(.*)(?=\?)
```

BUT I need the expression to use ECMAScript (javascript) so I cannot use the lookahead function.

I also need to remove the "/comm" in the matched string so the URL is a conventional LinkedIn profile URL. Perhaps a replace string function?

What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by *javascript cannot use the lookahead* ? It clearly can...

Comment: Have you found out a suitable answer, or can we help you further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pick one :)

I would go with one of the two last

**What if you could create sub-matches within a match?**

I think what you're looking for is [capture groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) so you can specify which part of the match you're interested in keeping within the array returned by `.match(...)`

Regarding your use-case it will let you give a general pattern to be able to match the specific line of the email where you'll get the url, so you can filter out junk, and a sub-pattern for the actual parts you're interested in keeping:

```
var regex = /View profile: (https:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/)comm\/([^?]+)/;
```

Here the parentheses say you will want to keep the matching part for later usage. executing `input.match(regex)` will yield an array with [0] being the whole match, [1] being your first capture group, [2] the next one and so on.

So we have two capturing groups:

1. `https://www.linkedin.com/` which could be discarded entirely and hard-coded in the output, given that it never changes
2. anything after `comm/` until we reach a `?` or consume the entire string

It's then as trivial as concatenating both of these to get the public profile url you're expecting

```js
var input = "View profile: https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&trk=4ceml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta&trkEmail=3Deml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta-null-21a89%dopkdokpokks%7Ezx-null-neptune%2Fprofile%7Evanity%2Eview&lipi=6guge%3Ali%3Apage%3Aemail_email_accept_invite_single_01%j3oijsdoij3oi%2FopIi4P20rA%3D%3D";
var regex = /View profile: (https:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/)comm\/([^?]+)/;
var result = input.match(regex);
var url = result[1] + result[2];
console.log(url);
```

**What if you actually wanted to make sure the original url included a query string, even though you don't intend to keep it**

In that case, if you want to make sure the url is actually followed by a query string (`?midToken=...`), which is a kind of `lookahead`, then you can append `\?` at the end of the first regex which will force the full match to at least include a `?` character (fragile, but should be sufficient for your needs). Then no matter if you wanted to match `View profile:` as a sort of `lookbehind` when matching the url you will **capture** and extract the part without the query string even though the regex pattern includes the starting `?` to consider what is a match.

```js
var input = "View profile: https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&trk=4ceml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta&trkEmail=3Deml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta-null-21a89%dopkdokpokks%7Ezx-null-neptune%2Fprofile%7Evanity%2Eview&lipi=6guge%3Ali%3Apage%3Aemail_email_accept_invite_single_01%j3oijsdoij3oi%2FopIi4P20rA%3D%3D";
var regex = /View profile: (https:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/)comm\/([^?]+)\?/;
var result = input.match(regex)
var url = result[1] + result[2];
console.log(url);
```

**It's still quite brittle, what should be a match?**

Although don't forget that regex can be tricky and you really have to understand how the input is formatted and how much this format can be trusted and sufficiently unique to not match something else entirely.

What if there was a `/comm/unsubscribe`, or a url that goes deeper like `/comm/in/user-123456/message` instead of `/in` somewhere in those emails? Let's harden the pattern a bit more to make sure we get the `/in/` followed by anything which isn't a `?` nor a `/`. There are a lot of ways to keep improving and securing the regex, but in the end, it's always a compromise.

```
var regex = /View profile: (https:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/)comm\/(in\/[^?/]+)/;
```

```js
var input = "View profile: https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&trk=4ceml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta&trkEmail=3Deml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta-null-21a89%dopkdokpokks%7Ezx-null-neptune%2Fprofile%7Evanity%2Eview&lipi=6guge%3Ali%3Apage%3Aemail_email_accept_invite_single_01%j3oijsdoij3oi%2FopIi4P20rA%3D%3D";
var regex = /View profile: (https:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/)comm\/(in\/[^?/]+)/;
var result = input.match(regex);
var url = result[1] + result[2];
console.log(url);
```

**Can you make it using `String.replace` in a single pass?**

Sure, when you do that, you'll want to add `.*` at both endings of your pattern in order to actually replace the whole input string with the values of the capture groups. Those values can be accessed straight from within the replacement string by using `$1` for the first capture group, `$2` for the second and so on. In this specific case we would want the following replacement string: `'$1$2'`

```js
var input = "View profile: https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&trk=4ceml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta&trkEmail=3Deml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta-null-21a89%dopkdokpokks%7Ezx-null-neptune%2Fprofile%7Evanity%2Eview&lipi=6guge%3Ali%3Apage%3Aemail_email_accept_invite_single_01%j3oijsdoij3oi%2FopIi4P20rA%3D%3D";
var url = input.replace(
  /.*View profile: (https:\/\/www\.linkedin\.com\/)comm\/(in\/[^?/]+).*/,
  '$1$2'
);
console.log(url);
```

Comment: This is perfect! I used the second to last. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has some libraries that can extract the various components of a URL.  But in this simple case, you may match everything from `http/https` until hitting the `?` which is the start of the query parameter:

```js
var input = "https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&trk=4ceml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta&trkEmail=3Deml-email_accept_invite_single_01-hero-1-prof%7Ecta-null-21a89%dopkdokpokks%7Ezx-null-neptune%2Fprofile%7Evanity%2Eview&lipi=6guge%3Ali%3Apage%3Aemail_email_accept_invite_single_01%j3oijsdoij3oi%2FopIi4P20rA%3D%3D";
var url = input.replace(/\?.*$/, "");
console.log(url);
```

The approach used here is to strip off the `?` followed the query string.  Note that the replacement won't affect the input URL should it not have a query string.

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = "View profile: https://www.linkedin.com/comm/in/profile-name-12345678?midToken=5345EEGREGERG34&midSig=5DDGDFGDFGD&...";
const url = /^.*(http[^?]*)\?/.exec(input)[1];
```

Comment: Pretty dangerous to do `http[^?].*` cause you're matching `http` + ONE character which is not `?` + ANYTHING (.*) followed by a `?`. Additionally, we can't assume from OPs question wether the input really starts with `View profile` or is actually the whole email. So wouldn't use the leading `^` either and keep the pattern pretty restrictive

Comment: You're right, there was an extra dot there. Edited it out

Comment: :) and then, does it make sense to allow `http@` to be a match, or `https://www.facebook.com` ?

Comment: Assuming additional random text in input, opens possibility for other linkedin profiles mentioned in the same email

Comment: Correct, what I'm trying to say is the variable part really is `profile-name-12345678` so given that the intent is to generate public linkedin urls out of email notifications, it's definitely safer to build the regex with this in mind